# Javascript: How does the carriage return work?

Tags: javascript, variables, escaping, carriage-return

I am going through the Javascript course on FreeCodeCamp.com and am stuck at this challenge, 'Escape Sequences in Strings':

> Assign the following three lines of text into the single variable
>   `myStr` using escape sequences.
>
> ```
> FirstLine
> \SecondLine\
> ThirdLine
> ```
>
> You will need to use escape sequences to insert special characters
>   correctly. You will also need to follow the spacing as it looks above,
>   with no spaces between escape sequences or words.
>
> Here is the text with the escape sequences written out.
>
> "FirstLine newline backslash SecondLine backslash carriage-return
>   ThirdLine"

Here is how I'm writing the code example:

```
var myStr = "Firstline\n\\Secondline\\\rThirdline";
```

The check requires there to be only one `\n`. The `\r` doesn't seem to function properly. I have tried different work arounds and searching hasn't provided any direction. I have tried using 'console' in the developer window of the browser and it appears `\n` is working but the `\r` is not.

1. Is the carriage-return not working?
2. Am I misunderstanding the lesson?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it with carriage returns is that they precede newlines so I think it would have to be `/r/nThirdline` for the carriage return to apply.

Comment: This would add a second newline command which is forbidden in the instructions.

Answer (score 0):

According to the book 'Javascript Bible' by Danny Goodman, chapter 15 'The String Objects', section 'Special Inline Characters':

"In most cases, browsers ignore carriage returns or render them like spaces."

https://books.google.com/books?id=WMr2NEG88icC&pg=PT262&lpg=PT262&dq=javascript+carriage+return&source=bl&ots=dWFLqN0rlO&sig=eZGo_74AHZq_4e2pxmtiqXz6l9s&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwivlMaEqu_QAhWBOSYKHSviBM44HhDoAQgjMAI#v=onepage&q=javascript%20carriage%20return&f=false

This might be a bug in how FreeCodeCamp checks this particular lesson. The code is probably rendered in the browser and so the check will always fail.